# header image doesn't show when the position is relative

Tags: html, css

I want to make a header with background image and it cover the page. So here's my code.

```css
.header {
        background: url('img/bg-01.png') center center;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<header class="header" id="top">

</header>
<div class="container text-center">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap css anyway. But, the header didn't show and when I change the position to absolute, the header appeared. But the content after the header doesn't show at all. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't see the header is because you've used a percentaged based height. Try adding a height in pixels like so

```
.header {
        background: url('http://placehold.it/400x400') center center;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 200px;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

If you wish to use a percentage based height then you'll need to make sure that the parent's height is also set. In this case, it would be the `body` and `html`. And there is no need for `position: relative` if you added this in an attempt to make it work for you.

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
.header {
        background: url('http://placehold.it/500x500') center center;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<header class="header" id="top">

</header>
<div class="container text-center">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Anne You're welcome - please accept this answer when you're able to by pressing the tick icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `min-height` to 100vh.

```css
header {
        background: url('http://placehold.it/500') center center;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100vh;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<header class="header" id="top">

</header>
<div class="container text-center">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

give height to header because div is empty only with background, so you have to add content or add height to div